# Query runs fine in SQL, but shows empty table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I'm having difficulties to display data from mysql database to PHP generated table. Interesting that query shown below runs fine in SQL, but when I try to wrap it in PHP, it displays empty table without giving any errors.

```
SELECT city.name, cinema.name, whattime, whichdate
FROM city, cinema, relationship
WHERE cinema.city = city.id
AND cinemaid = cinema.id
ORDER BY whichdate
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$usr = "admin";
$pwd = "";
$db = "dbname";
$host = "localhost";

$con = mysql_connect($host, $usr, $pwd) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "select city.name, cinema.name, whichdate, whattime ";
$sql .= "from city, cinema, relationship ";
$sql .= "where cinema.city = city.id ";
$sql .= "and cinemaid = cinema.id ";
$sql .= "order by whichdate";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "<table id='premiere'>";
echo "<tr> <th>CITY</th> <th>CINEMA</th> <th>DATE</th> <th>TIME</th></tr>";
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $result['city.name'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $result['cinema.name'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result['relationship.whichdate'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result['relationship.whattime'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";    
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the result of mysql_error()?  Have you tried a simpler query that you know will return a result, such as "select 1;"?   Try using mysqli instead of the mysql functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fetched array will not include the table names as array keys, only the column names (as in `$result['whichname']`)

Use column aliases for `city.name` and `cinema.name` to differentiate them.

```
$sql = "select city.name AS cityname, cinema.name AS cinemaname, whichdate, whattime ";
//--------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$sql .= "from city, cinema, relationship ";
$sql .= "where cinema.city = city.id ";
$sql .= "and cinemaid = cinema.id ";
$sql .= "order by whichdate";
```

Then, instead of:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $result['city.name'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $result['cinema.name'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result['relationship.whichdate'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result['relationship.whattime'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

use only the column names (or aliases) as array keys:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $result['cityname'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $result['cinemaname'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result['whichdate'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $result['whattime'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: thanks for fast response! but if I write 'name' in first two<td>, then outcome will be the same - in both columns showing name of cinema. I have to get name of the city in first column, while cinemas name is on second. any ideas? thanks!

Comment: @bojar did you see the first part above? Use column aliases `city.name AS cityname, cinema.name AS cinemaname`. Make sure you've refreshed the page to see the most recent edit